# Inequality for recursive-defined values

Tags: inequality, recurrence-relations

$f_{n+2} = \frac{6}{5}f_{n+1}-f_{n}, f_0 = 0,  f_1 = 1$
I need to prove that $f_n < 5/4$

I found that $f_{n} = \frac{1}{8} i 5^{1-n} \left((3-4 i)^n-(3+4 i)^n\right)$ and spend much time for efforts to solve this equality, but end in failure..

Comment: I think you need to doublecheck your closed form.  $f_n$ is clearly real valued, not complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we take $z=\frac{3-4i}{5}$ we have that:
$$ f_n = \frac{5i}{8}(z^n-\bar{z}^n) $$
but since $z$ belongs to the unit circle so does $z^n$ and $|z^n-\bar{z}^n|$ cannot exceed $2$.